# String Split a phrase into sentences

Tags: c#, strings, .net-core

Hello this is a Console App(.Net Core) in Visual Studio 2019 and i am trying to split a string into sentences and then add them into a dictionary with Key the first word of the sentence and Value the sentence itself.
I have the following code and i wonder if the way i did it has of course a better way to handle it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StringParse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string phrase = @"MHD001|LOCCOD|GRCACS|20191117|133601|CB|trx_grcacs_tsk_20191117133601498|
TSK001|GLS|GRCACS|59144|59144|2|TU|93000161357|TRACE|INF|DE 800|please send us the completely address information-thanks|68481|20191117|133555|
TSA001|X|
TSI001|3655|please send us the completely address information-thanks|66510|
TSI001|5637|80337|61335|
TSI001|5841|DE|61313|
MTR001|5|";
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            string sentenceSeparator = @"\b[A-Z]{3}\d{3}\b";
            string[] words = phrase.Split('|');

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                //If current word array matches the regex
                if (words[i].Equals(sentenceSeparator))
                {
                    // If the current array value doesn't match, then continue the current line.
                    sb.Append(words[i]);
                    sb.Append(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        // on the 1st iteration, we don't need a new line before the text value.
                        sb.Append(words[i]);
                        sb.Append(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(words[i]);
                        sb.Append(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
            string[] sentences = sb.ToString().Split('\r');

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            Regex regx = new Regex(sentenceSeparator);

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.
                Matches(phrase, sentenceSeparator,
                RegexOptions.Compiled |
                RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

            for (int i = 1; i < matches.Count; ++i)
            {
                phrase = phrase
                    .Replace(matches[i].Value,
                    Environment.NewLine + matches[i].Value);
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            Dictionary<Match, string> dic = matches.Zip(sentences, (x, y)
                 => new { Key = x, Value = y }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<Match, string> kvp in dic)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}" + Environment.NewLine + "Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

output will be like that:

```
Key = MHD001
Value = MHD001 LOCCOD GRCACS 20191117 133601 CB trx_grcacs_tsk_20191117133601498
Key = TSK001
Value = TSK001 GLS GRCACS 59144 59144 2 TU 93000161357 TRACE INF DE 800 please send us the completely address information-thanks 68481 20191117 133555
Key = TSA001
Value = TSA001 X
Key = TSI001
Value = TSI001 3655 please send us the completely address information-thanks 66510
Key = TSI001
Value = TSI001 5637 80337 61335
Key = TSI001
Value = TSI001 5841 DE 61313
Key = MTR001
Value = MTR001 5
```

Comment: Did you copy the code directly from your IDE? I am asking because in the first loop the whole `if..else..if..else` seems senseless because in each branch the code is doing the exactly same thing.

Comment: Yes i did copy it from the IDE..
first i split the phrase into words. then with stringbuilder and the regex i made it like sentence, then i added to another array. 
I do not have experience with C# and thats why i wonder if this is ok

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work.  It creates an error when compiling with Framework 4.8.  `MatchCollection` doesn't contain a `Zip` method.

Comment: @tinstaafl good catch. Using `matches.Cast<Match>().Zip...` will succeed without an error, and the dictionary has duplicated keys, thats just strange!

Comment: Well, maybe it isn't that strange because the key is a `Match` which is different for each `Match` in the `MatchCollection`.

Comment: @tinstaafl how do you say it doesn't work?
i had it run ,the console app, several times and i got the output i provided.
As you can see in the phrase it has some keys that are the same.
`Dictionary` contains `Zip` not the `MatchCollection`

Comment: Framework is 4.7.2

Comment: `matches` is a `MatchCollection` not a `Dictionary`.  No version of `MatchCollection` contains a `Zip` method.  It can't work as it is.  As @Heslacher pointed out it only works with the added `Cast` method.

Comment: The one thing i do not understand is that i posted this code on this particular community in order to get my code reviewed and hope to get better solution and better explanation for my future coding style.
Even though my code is being criticized about every little bit of things expert coders find. 
I do accept every criticism for the code i produced but that's not the point i believe in this StackExchange site. I do not hunt score or badges i just want to be a better coder.
Even with `Cast` or not this code runs and it produces the output i provided.

Comment: In order to review your code the question needs to be **on topic** which means your code needs to work. We just want to help you making your question on topic.  `Zip` is an extension method taking `IEnumerable<T>` but `MatchCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`. I would like to suggest that you create a new console project pasting your posted code and see what your IDE tells you about the `Zip()` method.

Comment: @Heslacher i did copy-paste my code to a new console app and i just added this `using System.Linq;` and it works the same. Sorry but i can not understand the problem with `Zip`

Comment: @Heslacher i added the `matches.Cast<Match>().Zip...` also but still it needs this `using System.Linq;` in order to work.
can we talk somehow in a chat and don't fill the post with comments if thats ok with you?

Comment: As it stands, the code as presented looks like it can't quite work as intended, notably how the `sentences` array is constructed would not produce the results outlined as target results. Additionally there is some ambiguity around the use of the `Zip` extension method that should be definitively resolved before this code can be reviewed. As such I have closed this question for now until the code for review is verified to be working as expected. Thanks for understanding

Comment: @Vogel612 Sure i understand. I am using Console App(.Net Core) in Visual Studio 2019 and the only dependencies i am having is `Microsoft.NetCore.App`
and the targeting framework is `4.7.2`

Comment: Alright, while I don't have a windows at hand, I was able to verify the code as posted works when running it against dotnet core 3.0.100 when targeting netcoreapp3.0. As such I have reopened the question

Comment: Just add ```Cast<Match>()``` and it works ``` Dictionary<Match, string> dic = matches.Cast<Match>().Zip(sentences, (x, y) => new { Key = x, Value = y }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole `if`..`else`..`if`..`else` inside the first loop is senseless because each branch does exactly the same.

---

Using `Split('|')` and combining the resulting array with one space `" "` is the same like replacing `|` by a space.

---

The `Regex regx = new Regex(sentenceSeparator);` is superflous because you don't use `regex` at all.

---

The loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < matches.Count; ++i)
{
    phrase = phrase
        .Replace(matches[i].Value,
        Environment.NewLine + matches[i].Value);
}
```

is superflous because you aren't using `phrase` afterwards.

---

As it seems (untested) you can use `Zip()` with a `MatchCollection` if you use .NET Core 3.0.100 but to make your code runnable without .NET Core you should change

```
Dictionary<Match, string> dic = matches.Zip(sentences, (x, y)
             => new { Key = x, Value = y }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

to

```
Dictionary<Match, string> dic = matches.Cast<Match>().Zip(sentences, (x, y)
             => new { Key = x, Value = y }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

---

It comes for sure from copying the code (which seems to be posted using `Shift + Enter` for `phrase`) from this question to the IDE....if you inspect the result of `dict` you will see that from the second item on the `Value` is prepended by a `\n`. This can be prevented by using `TrimStart('\n')` on `y` at `new { Key = x, Value = y }`.

---

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string phrase = @"MHD001|LOCCOD|GRCACS|20191117|133601|CB|trx_grcacs_tsk_20191117133601498|TSK001|GLS|GRCACS|59144|59144|2|TU|93000161357|TRACE|INF|DE 800|please send us the completely address information-thanks|68481|20191117|133555|TSA001|X|TSI001|3655|please send us the completely address information-thanks|66510|TSI001|5637|80337|61335|TSI001|5841|DE|61313|MTR001|5|";

        string[] sentences = phrase.Replace('|',' ').Split('\r');
        string sentencePattern = @"\b[A-Z]{3}\d{3}\b";

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.
            Matches(phrase, sentencePattern,
            RegexOptions.Compiled |
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

        Dictionary<Match, string> dic = matches.Cast<Match>().Zip(sentences, (x, y)
             => new { Key = x, Value = y.TrimStart('\n') }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Match, string> kvp in dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}" + Environment.NewLine + "Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments and the great review.